# Python: Summing Odd/Even Random Numbers Generates TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, random, range, typeerror, iterable

Yes, this question has been asked, but I cannot seem to apply the answers to my problem. There are several parts to this problem, and this is the biggest obstacle I've hit.

I need to generate a random list of 10 numbers between 10 & 90. From those random numbers, I need to sum the totals of both the even and odd numbers.

```
def playlist():
    nums = []
    for nums in range(10):
        # Get random list of 10 numbers
        my_nums = random.randint(10, 90)
        print (my_nums,end=' ')
        even = []
        odd = []
        for x in my_nums:
            if x % 2 == 0:
                even.append[x]
                print(even)
            else:
                odd.append[x]
                print(odd)
```

When I run this, sometimes I get one or two numbers (usually the first two odd numbers), but mostly I get TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Not gonna lie - my first language is PHP, not Python and that's becoming a huge problem for me :(

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to loop over `my_nums` as if it was a list of numbers, but it is actually just one integer. BTW, you are also defining `nums` to be an empty list and in the very next line you delete that and put an integer into it.

Comment: `my_nums` is an integer. You can't for-in over a number.

Comment: @zvone - I don't know why but that's what the assignment called for was to create an empty list called nums

Comment: @andrew-l - I modified for x in my_nums to for x in range(my_nums) and that stopped that error - now I just have it printing the odd and even numbers between 0 & 9 lol

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this.

```
def playlist():
    nums1 = []
    for nums in range(10):
        # Get random list of 10 numbers
        my_nums = random.randint(10, 90)
        nums1.append(my_nums)
        print my_nums


    even = []
    odd = []
    for x in nums1:
      if x % 2 == 0:
          even.append(x)
          print(even)
      else:
          odd.append(x)
          print(odd)


playlist()
```

Comment: really?, remove the print statement, I get that, what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Sorry about the indentation, that was a little off. It should work fine now.

Comment: after you finish writing the function, call the function somewhere. At the end of the script, type the function name. That should do the trick.

Comment: yeah scratch my previous comment...I'd also forgotten to import random

this list is printing, but I get
21 30 46 10 10 71 47 42 84 53 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bernadette\Desktop\0520 Intermediate Computer Programming\program_p1.py", line 21, in <module>
    playlist()
  File "C:\Users\Bernadette\Desktop\0520 Intermediate Computer Programming\program_p1.py", line 18, in playlist
    odd.append[x]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: oh wait - hang on! I switched even.append[x] to even.append(x) and I'm getting a much better result

Comment: thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction! please see my answer below to see how it finally played out :)

Comment: If the user did help you, please consider accepting their answer :)

Comment: @BernadetteMcCarthy, can you please upvote and accept the answer, if the answer did help you.

Answer (score 2):

Creating list with randoms

```
n = [random.randint(10,90) for x in range(10)]
```

Getting even and odds:

```
even = [x for x in n if x % 2 == 0]
odd = [x for x in n if x % 2 == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you seem to have misunderstood:

- `range(10)` will give you (something that looks like) this list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

  - You can use it with a for-loop to do something 10 times
- `random.randint(10, 90)` will give you a single random number between 10 and 90 (not a list)

With this information we can change your script to:

```
import random

even_sum = 0
odd_sum = 0
for number_of_turns in range(10):
    # Get a random number
    number_this_turn = random.randint(10, 90)
    print(number_this_turn,end=' ')
    if number_this_turn % 2 == 0:
        even_sum += number_this_turn
        print("Sum of even numbers so far:", even_sum)
    else:
        odd_sum += number_this_turn
        print("Sum of odd numbers so far:", odd_sum)

print("Final sum of even numbers:", even_sum)
print("Final sum of odd numbers:", odd_sum)
```

But we can do better. You will learn that in Python, you will want very often to define a list (or an iterable) with the terms you need then do something with every term. So we can change your script to:

```
import random

even_sum = 0
odd_sum = 0

random_numbers = [random.randint(10, 90) for x in range(10)]

for number in random_numbers:
    print(number,end=' ')
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even_sum += number
        print("Sum of even numbers so far:", even_sum)
    else:
        odd_sum += number
        print("Sum of odd numbers so far:", odd_sum)

print("Final sum of even numbers:", even_sum)
print("Final sum of odd numbers:", odd_sum)
```

`random_numbers = [random.randint(10, 90) for x in range(10)]` is using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate a list of 10 random numbers. You can then do a for-loop on each of these numbers where you can add to the evens' sum or to the odds' sum.

You can even simplify it even further like in @Take_Care_ 's answer but I guess you have a lot more to learn before you reach this level.

Comment: I appreciate this @evensf - I'm completely ignorant of Python even though this is "Intermediate Computer Programming", I just barely passed the Intro class and even in PHP I tend to still fall back on my procedural ways - and it seems as though everyday I move further and further away from actual hands-on coding :(

Comment: "Before You reach that level" ah, You are so kind for me :) get the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the comments, you can't write `for x in` followed by a number. I guess what you want is `for x in range(my_nums)` rather than `for x in my_nums`.

Comment: yep switching to range(my_nums) did correct that error

Comment: but then range(my_nums) will not be random integers, ain't so?

Answer (score 0):

This is ultimately what I needed:

```
def playlist():
nums = []
for nums1 in range(10):
    # Get random list of 10 numbers
    my_nums = random.randint(10, 90)
    nums.append(my_nums)
    print (my_nums,end=' ')


even = []
odd = []
for x in nums:
  if x % 2 == 0:
      even.append(x)
  else:
      odd.append(x)
print ("\n")
print("Total of Even Numbers: ",sum(even))
print ("\n")
print("Total of Odd Numbers: ",sum(odd))
```

Thanks to everyone for their help...yes I know the call to run the function is missing - like I said this is just one part of the program :)

Answer (score 0):

Following code works:

```
"""
I need to generate a random list of 10 numbers between 10 & 90. From those random numbers, I need to sum the totals of both the even and odd numbers.
"""
from random import randint

    MIN = 10
    MAX = 90
    sum_odds = sum_evens = 0

    for i in range(10):
        r = randint(MIN,MAX)
        if r % 2:
            sum_odds += r
        else:
            sum_evens += r
    return sum_evens, sum_odds
```